# Command wrapper and completion

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I often write something like this:

```
cp -r folder-0.0.1 ~/temp
cp -r folder-0.2.2 ~/temp
cp -r folder-1.0.0 ~/temp
```

Template: `<comand> <name>-<version> <path>`

But instead, I'd like to write this:

```
do_something 0.0.1
do_something 0.2.2
do_something 1.0.0
```

Template: `<alias> <version>`

Can I do it easily in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) using aliases?

I would also like appropriate completion with <kbd>tab</kbd> key to work correctly. How can I program [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s completion to achieve this?

Comment: Regarding the close request: the question is also about programming completions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Not with aliases.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080)

```
do_something () {
  cp -r folder-"$1" ~/temp
}
```

Comment: ok, but I have one trouble with tab+tab autocomplete.
When I use tab+tab Bash write folder-<version> after so_something. And when I do it it looks like folder-folder-<version>. Can it be fixed?

Comment: bash write = bash propose to write in that case.

Comment: Sure. Modify the autocomplete functions. No, I don't know how.

Comment: I think it should be common sense to propose atleast some (atleast minor) sort of error handling. Check that you atleast have an argument sent along to the function and then do the work, it's one line of code extra. Without it, the function is really flaky.

Answer (score 1):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams already mentioned, don't use aliases. In fact, it's even written in the [*Aliases* section of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases):

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

So you'll need that function:

```
do_something() {
    [[ -n $1 ]] && cp -rnvt ~/test folder-"$1"
}
```

If you don't like the way I wrote the `cp` with all its options, just remove them. For info:

- `-n` so as to not overwrite an existing file/folder
- `-v` so as to be verbose
- The directory following `-t` is the target directory

(I like to write my `cp`s like this, your version of `cp` might not handle this, but very likely does).

There's also a check to make sure an argument was given before launching the `cp`.

So far there's nothing better than the other answers. Regarding completion, here's what you can do:

```
_do_something() {
    COMPREPLY=( $(
        shopt -s nullglob extglob
        files=( folder-+([[:digit:].])/ )
        for ((i=0;i<${#files[@]};++i)); do
            files[i]=${files[i]#folder-}
            files[i]=${files[i]%/}
        done
        compgen -W "${files[*]}" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
     ) )
     return 0
}

complete -F _do_something do_something
```

Put this in your `.bashrc` (even though it's probably not the best place for completions, you'll tweak all this when you're more experienced) and enjoy!

From here you'll want to extend this until it becomes a 100000 lines wonderful script. For example I added the `-n` option in `cp` (I believe it's a cool security feature). You could then want to add options to the `do_something` function, for example an option `--force` that will remove this `-n` option. I won't do it for you (and it's beyond the scope of this answer), it's not that difficult, though. Then make sure you also alter the completion feature accordingly! It's a lot of fun.